# How can I add the API23 plugin in older version of the android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have older version of the android studio. I will display it for you using the following image. Can I add the `API23` in the `target SDK:` and also in the `Compile with:` items??

[image]

Comment: Just update your sdk to api 23 and it will reflect here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download the latest versions of Android SDK tools, Android SDK Platform-tools, and Android SDK Build-tools from the SDK Manager. Your IDE will be updated with up to the latest API level for the *Target SDK* and *compile with*.